# Add To Cart With Notes (woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am at very basic knowledge of coding and I am trying to do my own snippet to Add To Woocommerce cart upon Gravity Forms Submission.

I also want each item to have a custom note in the item meta.

The other problem I am facing is the form is coming up with an error message (a whole page saying 'string') BUT it is still adding "ONE" item to the cart - not all. No item note is being added.

I understand that it could be too long?

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong here?

Thanks :)

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_12', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    // use this to find out $entry output
    var_dump($entry);
    
$if=rgar( $entry, '2990' ); 
$note = rgar( $entry, '1601' );
    $cart_item_data =rgar( $entry, '1601' );
$Product1AM01 = rgar( $entry,2639);
$Product2AFP601=rgar( $entry,2671);
$Product3AFP6015=rgar( $entry,2672);
$Product4AFID6SSU=rgar( $entry,2669);
$Product5AFID8SSU=rgar( $entry,2670);
$Product6AP101=rgar( $entry,2678);
$Product7AW8110=rgar( $entry,2685);
$Product8AW7100SU=rgar( $entry,2575);
$Product9AAB100=rgar( $entry,2696);
$Product10EGA60=rgar( $entry,2688);
$Product11AA01=rgar( $entry,2576);
$Product12AAS50=rgar( $entry,2577);
$Product13AW8000SU=rgar( $entry,2578);
$Product14BHB2538=rgar( $entry,2687);
$Product15AB3=rgar( $entry,2579);
$Product16ABD10=rgar( $entry,2580);
$Product17ABS1010SU=rgar( $entry,2581);
$Product18ABC10=rgar( $entry,2956);
$Product19ABC10SU=rgar( $entry,2658);
$Product20ST30SU=rgar( $entry,2582);
$Product21FCP03=rgar( $entry,2689);
$Product22FCP06=rgar( $entry,2690);
$Product23ABCH100SU=rgar( $entry,2650);
$Product24ABCH100=rgar( $entry,2660);
$Product25ABCH25=rgar( $entry,2949);
$Product26ABCH25SU=rgar( $entry,2647);
$Product27ABCH50SU=rgar( $entry,2648);
$Product28ABCH50=rgar( $entry,2945);
$Product29ABCH75=rgar( $entry,2661);
$Product30ABCH75SU=rgar( $entry,2649);
$Product31ACD1010SSU=rgar( $entry,2583);
$Product32ACD1020SSU=rgar( $entry,2584);
$Product33ACD2020SSU=rgar( $entry,2585);
$Product34AF100SU=rgar( $entry,2665);
$Product35AF25SU=rgar( $entry,2586);
$Product36AF50SU=rgar( $entry,2587);
$Product37AF75SU=rgar( $entry,2588);
$Product38ACA150=rgar( $entry,2589);
$Product39CWD001=rgar( $entry,2590);
$Product40ACM100SU=rgar( $entry,2659);
$Product41ACM150SU=rgar( $entry,2662);
$Product42ACM25SU=rgar( $entry,2663);
$Product43ACM50SU=rgar( $entry,2591);
$Product44ACM75SU=rgar( $entry,2592);
$Product45AD1007B=rgar( $entry,2664);
$Product46AD1000=rgar( $entry,2654);
$Product47AD1001=rgar( $entry,2655);
$Product48PTD06=rgar( $entry,2616);
$Product49AWDPB01=rgar( $entry,2593);
$Product50ACE50SU=rgar( $entry,2646);
$Product51ATB130=rgar( $entry,2594);
$Product52ATB130SU=rgar( $entry,2694);
$Product53AEP1SSU=rgar( $entry,2595);
$Product54EB001=rgar( $entry,2596);
$Product55AFP701=rgar( $entry,2598);
$Product56AFP50125=rgar( $entry,2651);
$Product57AFP350=rgar( $entry,2599);
$Product58AFP506=rgar( $entry,2652);
$Product59AFP501=rgar( $entry,2601);
$Product60AFP5015=rgar( $entry,2600);
$Product61AFS001=rgar( $entry,2619);
$Product62AGB001=rgar( $entry,2602);
$Product63AGL001=rgar( $entry,2603);
$Product64AFP11=rgar( $entry,2625);
$Product65AFB13=rgar( $entry,2656);
$Product66AGS755SSU=rgar( $entry,2677);
$Product67AGS753SSU=rgar( $entry,2604);
$Product68AGNPF10=rgar( $entry,2675);
$Product69AGNPF02=rgar( $entry,2605);
$Product70AFH50SU=rgar( $entry,2666);
$Product71AFH75SU=rgar( $entry,2645);
$Product72AII5000=rgar( $entry,2947);
$Product73AII2500=rgar( $entry,2946);
$Product74KD160=rgar( $entry,2608);
$Product75APD101SSU=rgar( $entry,2611);
$Product76APD102SSU=rgar( $entry,2612);
$Product77APD100SSU=rgar( $entry,2614);
$Product78APD50SSU=rgar( $entry,2613);
$Product79APD75SSU=rgar( $entry,2653);
$Product80AP312SU=rgar( $entry,2609);
$Product81AP325DSU=rgar( $entry,2679);
$Product82ND90=rgar( $entry,2622);
$Product83APD100S=rgar( $entry,2680);
$Product84APD101S=rgar( $entry,2681);
$Product85APD102S=rgar( $entry,2682);
$Product86APD50S=rgar( $entry,2683);
$Product87APD75S=rgar( $entry,2684);
$Product88AGS75=rgar( $entry,2676);
$Product89ABN10SU=rgar( $entry,2695);
$Product90ABN10=rgar( $entry,2626);
$Product91ASN096P=rgar( $entry,2615);
$Product92AP10125=rgar( $entry,2617);
$Product93AP1015=rgar( $entry,2618);
$Product94PPC60=rgar( $entry,2691);
$Product95AWP16100SU=rgar( $entry,2686);
$Product96ASP12=rgar( $entry,2620);
$Product97ASC13=rgar( $entry,2621);
$Product98AFSB10=rgar( $entry,2673);
$Product99AFSB10SU=rgar( $entry,2674);
$Product100AFHSB100=rgar( $entry,2667);
$Product101AFHSB100SU=rgar( $entry,2668);
$Product102AW1060SU=rgar( $entry,2597);
$Product103SOFTTWR=rgar( $entry,2692);
$Product104ASP100SU=rgar( $entry,2624);
$Product105Stingoes25=rgar( $entry,2963);
$Product106AT25SU=rgar( $entry,2610);
$Product107AF9=rgar( $entry,2627);
$Product108USP19=rgar( $entry,2693);
$Product109AW1510SU=rgar( $entry,2644);
$Product110APWC7535SU=rgar( $entry,2623);
$Product111AWD13SSU=rgar( $entry,2628);
$Product112AWD14SSU=rgar( $entry,2629);
$Product113AWD15SSU=rgar( $entry,2630);
$Product114AFT25SU=rgar( $entry,2631);
$Product115AFPW010SU=rgar( $entry,2970);
$Product116AFPW015SU=rgar( $entry,2977);
$Quantity1AM01=rgar( $entry,2835);
$Quantity2AFP601=rgar( $entry,2793);
$Quantity3AFP6015=rgar( $entry,2799);
$Quantity4AFID6SSU=rgar( $entry,2781);
$Quantity5AFID8SSU=rgar( $entry,2787);
$Quantity6AP101=rgar( $entry,2841);
$Quantity7AW8110=rgar( $entry,2889);
$Quantity8AW7100SU=rgar( $entry,119);
$Quantity9AAB100=rgar( $entry,175);
$Quantity10EGA60=rgar( $entry,2907);
$Quantity11AA01=rgar( $entry,1278);
$Quantity12AAS50=rgar( $entry,198);
$Quantity13AW8000SU=rgar( $entry,216);
$Quantity14BHB2538=rgar( $entry,2901);
$Quantity15AB3=rgar( $entry,1987);
$Quantity16ABD10=rgar( $entry,234);
$Quantity17ABS1010SU=rgar( $entry,270);
$Quantity18ABC10=rgar( $entry,2960);
$Quantity19ABC10SU=rgar( $entry,2548);
$Quantity20ST30SU=rgar( $entry,306);
$Quantity21FCP03=rgar( $entry,2913);
$Quantity22FCP06=rgar( $entry,2919);
$Quantity23ABCH100SU=rgar( $entry,2530);
$Quantity24ABCH100=rgar( $entry,2943);
$Quantity25ABCH25=rgar( $entry,2953);
$Quantity26ABCH25SU=rgar( $entry,2534);
$Quantity27ABCH50SU=rgar( $entry,2542);
$Quantity28ABCH50=rgar( $entry,2713);
$Quantity29ABCH75=rgar( $entry,2719);
$Quantity30ABCH75SU=rgar( $entry,2538);
$Quantity31ACD1010SSU=rgar( $entry,324);
$Quantity32ACD1020SSU=rgar( $entry,342);
$Quantity33ACD2020SSU=rgar( $entry,360);
$Quantity34AF100SU=rgar( $entry,2757);
$Quantity35AF25SU=rgar( $entry,378);
$Quantity36AF50SU=rgar( $entry,396);
$Quantity37AF75SU=rgar( $entry,414);
$Quantity38ACA150=rgar( $entry,468);
$Quantity39CWD001=rgar( $entry,288);
$Quantity40ACM100SU=rgar( $entry,2731);
$Quantity41ACM150SU=rgar( $entry,2737);
$Quantity42ACM25SU=rgar( $entry,2743);
$Quantity43ACM50SU=rgar( $entry,522);
$Quantity44ACM75SU=rgar( $entry,540);
$Quantity45AD1007B=rgar( $entry,2751);
$Quantity46AD1000=rgar( $entry,2514);
$Quantity47AD1001=rgar( $entry,2518);
$Quantity48PTD06=rgar( $entry,1008);
$Quantity49AWDPB01=rgar( $entry,558);
$Quantity50ACE50SU=rgar( $entry,2554);
$Quantity51ATB130=rgar( $entry,576);
$Quantity52ATB130SU=rgar( $entry,2883);
$Quantity53AEP1SSU=rgar( $entry,1314);
$Quantity54EB001=rgar( $entry,612);
$Quantity55AFP701=rgar( $entry,630);
$Quantity56AFP50125=rgar( $entry,2526);
$Quantity57AFP350=rgar( $entry,2017);
$Quantity58AFP506=rgar( $entry,2522);
$Quantity59AFP501=rgar( $entry,1026);
$Quantity60AFP5015=rgar( $entry,2032);
$Quantity61AFS001=rgar( $entry,1404);
$Quantity62AGB001=rgar( $entry,684);
$Quantity63AGL001=rgar( $entry,1350);
$Quantity64AFP11=rgar( $entry,2246);
$Quantity65AFB13=rgar( $entry,2510);
$Quantity66AGS755SSU=rgar( $entry,2829);
$Quantity67AGS753SSU=rgar( $entry,702);
$Quantity68AGNPF10=rgar( $entry,2817);
$Quantity69AGNPF02=rgar( $entry,720);
$Quantity70AFH50SU=rgar( $entry,2763);
$Quantity71AFH75SU=rgar( $entry,2505);
$Quantity72AII5000=rgar( $entry,792);
$Quantity73AII2500=rgar( $entry,810);
$Quantity74KD160=rgar( $entry,864);
$Quantity75APD101SSU=rgar( $entry,1473);
$Quantity76APD102SSU=rgar( $entry,936);
$Quantity77APD100SSU=rgar( $entry,972);
$Quantity78APD50SSU=rgar( $entry,954);
$Quantity79APD75SSU=rgar( $entry,2560);
$Quantity80AP312SU=rgar( $entry,1368);
$Quantity81AP325DSU=rgar( $entry,2847);
$Quantity82ND90=rgar( $entry,1501);
$Quantity83APD100S=rgar( $entry,2853);
$Quantity84APD101S=rgar( $entry,2859);
$Quantity85APD102S=rgar( $entry,2865);
$Quantity86APD50S=rgar( $entry,2871);
$Quantity87APD75S=rgar( $entry,2877);
$Quantity88AGS75=rgar( $entry,2823);
$Quantity89ABN10SU=rgar( $entry,2725);
$Quantity90ABN10=rgar( $entry,1188);
$Quantity91ASN096P=rgar( $entry,990);
$Quantity92AP10125=rgar( $entry,1386);
$Quantity93AP1015=rgar( $entry,1487);
$Quantity94PPC60=rgar( $entry,2925);
$Quantity95AWP16100SU=rgar( $entry,2895);
$Quantity96ASP12=rgar( $entry,1080);
$Quantity97ASC13=rgar( $entry,1098);
$Quantity98AFSB10=rgar( $entry,2805);
$Quantity99AFSB10SU=rgar( $entry,2811);
$Quantity100AFHSB100=rgar( $entry,2769);
$Quantity101AFHSB100SU=rgar( $entry,2775);
$Quantity102AW1060SU=rgar( $entry,1332);
$Quantity103SOFTTWR=rgar( $entry,2931);
$Quantity104ASP100SU=rgar( $entry,1152);
$Quantity105Stingoes25=rgar( $entry,2967);
$Quantity106AT25SU=rgar( $entry,900);
$Quantity107AF9=rgar( $entry,1515);
$Quantity108USP19=rgar( $entry,2937);
$Quantity109AW1510SU=rgar( $entry,2482);
$Quantity110APWC7535SU=rgar( $entry,1134);
$Quantity111AWD13SSU=rgar( $entry,1206);
$Quantity112AWD14SSU=rgar( $entry,1224);
$Quantity113AWD15SSU=rgar( $entry,1242);
$Quantity114AFT25SU=rgar( $entry,1260);
$Quantity115AFPW010SU=rgar( $entry,2974);
$Quantity116AFPW015SU=rgar( $entry,2981);

        
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product1AM01,$Quantity1AM01);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product2AFP601,$Quantity2AFP601);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product3AFP6015,$Quantity3AFP6015);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product4AFID6SSU,$Quantity4AFID6SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product5AFID8SSU,$Quantity5AFID8SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product6AP101,$Quantity6AP101);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product7AW8110,$Quantity7AW8110);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product8AW7100SU,$Quantity8AW7100SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product9AAB100,$Quantity9AAB100);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product10EGA60,$Quantity10EGA60);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product11AA01,$Quantity11AA01);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product12AAS50,$Quantity12AAS50);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product13AW8000SU,$Quantity13AW8000SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product14BHB2538,$Quantity14BHB2538);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product15AB3,$Quantity15AB3);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product16ABD10,$Quantity16ABD10);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product17ABS1010SU,$Quantity17ABS1010SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product18ABC10,$Quantity18ABC10);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product19ABC10SU,$Quantity19ABC10SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product20ST30SU,$Quantity20ST30SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product21FCP03,$Quantity21FCP03);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product22FCP06,$Quantity22FCP06);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product23ABCH100SU,$Quantity23ABCH100SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product24ABCH100,$Quantity24ABCH100);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product25ABCH25,$Quantity25ABCH25);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product26ABCH25SU,$Quantity26ABCH25SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product27ABCH50SU,$Quantity27ABCH50SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product28ABCH50,$Quantity28ABCH50);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product29ABCH75,$Quantity29ABCH75);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product30ABCH75SU,$Quantity30ABCH75SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product31ACD1010SSU,$Quantity31ACD1010SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product32ACD1020SSU,$Quantity32ACD1020SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product33ACD2020SSU,$Quantity33ACD2020SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product34AF100SU,$Quantity34AF100SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product35AF25SU,$Quantity35AF25SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product36AF50SU,$Quantity36AF50SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product37AF75SU,$Quantity37AF75SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product38ACA150,$Quantity38ACA150);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product39CWD001,$Quantity39CWD001);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product40ACM100SU,$Quantity40ACM100SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product41ACM150SU,$Quantity41ACM150SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product42ACM25SU,$Quantity42ACM25SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product43ACM50SU,$Quantity43ACM50SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product44ACM75SU,$Quantity44ACM75SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product45AD1007B,$Quantity45AD1007B);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product46AD1000,$Quantity46AD1000);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product47AD1001,$Quantity47AD1001);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product48PTD06,$Quantity48PTD06);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product49AWDPB01,$Quantity49AWDPB01);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product50ACE50SU,$Quantity50ACE50SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product51ATB130,$Quantity51ATB130);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product52ATB130SU,$Quantity52ATB130SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product53AEP1SSU,$Quantity53AEP1SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product54EB001,$Quantity54EB001);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product55AFP701,$Quantity55AFP701);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product56AFP50125,$Quantity56AFP50125);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product57AFP350,$Quantity57AFP350);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product58AFP506,$Quantity58AFP506);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product59AFP501,$Quantity59AFP501);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product60AFP5015,$Quantity60AFP5015);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product61AFS001,$Quantity61AFS001);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product62AGB001,$Quantity62AGB001);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product63AGL001,$Quantity63AGL001);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product64AFP11,$Quantity64AFP11);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product65AFB13,$Quantity65AFB13);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product66AGS755SSU,$Quantity66AGS755SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product67AGS753SSU,$Quantity67AGS753SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product68AGNPF10,$Quantity68AGNPF10);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product69AGNPF02,$Quantity69AGNPF02);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product70AFH50SU,$Quantity70AFH50SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product71AFH75SU,$Quantity71AFH75SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product72AII5000,$Quantity72AII5000);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product73AII2500,$Quantity73AII2500);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product74KD160,$Quantity74KD160);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product75APD101SSU,$Quantity75APD101SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product76APD102SSU,$Quantity76APD102SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product77APD100SSU,$Quantity77APD100SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product78APD50SSU,$Quantity78APD50SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product79APD75SSU,$Quantity79APD75SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product80AP312SU,$Quantity80AP312SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product81AP325DSU,$Quantity81AP325DSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product82ND90,$Quantity82ND90);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product83APD100S,$Quantity83APD100S);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product84APD101S,$Quantity84APD101S);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product85APD102S,$Quantity85APD102S);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product86APD50S,$Quantity86APD50S);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product87APD75S,$Quantity87APD75S);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product88AGS75,$Quantity88AGS75);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product89ABN10SU,$Quantity89ABN10SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product90ABN10,$Quantity90ABN10);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product91ASN096P,$Quantity91ASN096P);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product92AP10125,$Quantity92AP10125);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product93AP1015,$Quantity93AP1015);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product94PPC60,$Quantity94PPC60);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product95AWP16100SU,$Quantity95AWP16100SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product96ASP12,$Quantity96ASP12);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product97ASC13,$Quantity97ASC13);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product98AFSB10,$Quantity98AFSB10);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product99AFSB10SU,$Quantity99AFSB10SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product100AFHSB100,$Quantity100AFHSB100);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product101AFHSB100SU,$Quantity101AFHSB100SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product102AW1060SU,$Quantity102AW1060SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product103SOFTTWR,$Quantity103SOFTTWR);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product104ASP100SU,$Quantity104ASP100SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product105Stingoes25,$Quantity105Stingoes25);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product106AT25SU,$Quantity106AT25SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product107AF9,$Quantity107AF9);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product108USP19,$Quantity108USP19);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product109AW1510SU,$Quantity109AW1510SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product110APWC7535SU,$Quantity110APWC7535SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product111AWD13SSU,$Quantity111AWD13SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product112AWD14SSU,$Quantity112AWD14SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product113AWD15SSU,$Quantity113AWD15SSU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product114AFT25SU,$Quantity114AFT25SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product115AFPW010SU,$Quantity115AFPW010SU);
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product116AFPW015SU,$Quantity116AFPW015SU);

foreach ($item->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
    $item->add_meta_data( 'Belonging to kit', $note, true );}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have altered my code so it now adds the items and custom meta to cart....

```
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    // use this to find out $entry output
    var_dump($entry);
    $doyouorder=rgar( $entry, '2990' );
$kitnote = rgar( $entry, '1601' );
$Product1AM01 = rgar( $entry,'2639');
$Product2AFP601=rgar( $entry,'2671');
$Product3AFP6015=rgar( $entry,'2672');
$Product4AFID6SSU=rgar( $entry,'2669');
$Product5AFID8SSU=rgar( $entry,'2670');
$Product6AP101=rgar( $entry,'2678');
$Product7AW8110=rgar( $entry,'2685');
$Product8AW7100SU=rgar( $entry,'2575');
$Product9AAB100=rgar( $entry,'2696');
$Product10EGA60=rgar( $entry,'2688');
$Product11AA01=rgar( $entry,'2576');
$Product12AAS50=rgar( $entry,'2577');
$Product13AW8000SU=rgar( $entry,'2578');
$Product14BHB2538=rgar( $entry,'2687');
$Product15AB3=rgar( $entry,'2579');
$Product16ABD10=rgar( $entry,'2580');
$Product17ABS1010SU=rgar( $entry,'2581');
$Product18ABC10=rgar( $entry,'2956');
$Product19ABC10SU=rgar( $entry,'2658');
$Product20ST30SU=rgar( $entry,'2582');
$Product21FCP03=rgar( $entry,'2689');
$Product22FCP06=rgar( $entry,'2690');
$Product23ABCH100SU=rgar( $entry,'2650');
$Product24ABCH100=rgar( $entry,'2660');
$Product25ABCH25=rgar( $entry,'2949');
$Product26ABCH25SU=rgar( $entry,'2647');
$Product27ABCH50SU=rgar( $entry,'2648');
$Product28ABCH50=rgar( $entry,'2945');
$Product29ABCH75=rgar( $entry,'2661');
$Product30ABCH75SU=rgar( $entry,'2649');
$Product31ACD1010SSU=rgar( $entry,'2583');
$Product32ACD1020SSU=rgar( $entry,'2584');
$Product33ACD2020SSU=rgar( $entry,'2585');
$Product34AF100SU=rgar( $entry,'2665');
$Product35AF25SU=rgar( $entry,'2586');
$Product36AF50SU=rgar( $entry,'2587');
$Product37AF75SU=rgar( $entry,'2588');
$Product38ACA150=rgar( $entry,'2589');
$Product39CWD001=rgar( $entry,'2590');
$Product40ACM100SU=rgar( $entry,'2659');
$Product41ACM150SU=rgar( $entry,'2662');
$Product42ACM25SU=rgar( $entry,'2663');
$Product43ACM50SU=rgar( $entry,'2591');
$Product44ACM75SU=rgar( $entry,'2592');
$Product45AD1007B=rgar( $entry,'2664');
$Product46AD1000=rgar( $entry,'2654');
$Product47AD1001=rgar( $entry,'2655');
$Product48PTD06=rgar( $entry,'2616');
$Product49AWDPB01=rgar( $entry,'2593');
$Product50ACE50SU=rgar( $entry,'2646');
$Product51ATB130=rgar( $entry,'2594');
$Product52ATB130SU=rgar( $entry,'2694');
$Product53AEP1SSU=rgar( $entry,'2595');
$Product54EB001=rgar( $entry,'2596');
$Product55AFP701=rgar( $entry,'2598');
$Product56AFP50125=rgar( $entry,'2651');
$Product57AFP350=rgar( $entry,'2599');
$Product58AFP506=rgar( $entry,'2652');
$Product59AFP501=rgar( $entry,'2601');
$Product60AFP5015=rgar( $entry,'2600');
$Product61AFS001=rgar( $entry,'2619');
$Product62AGB001=rgar( $entry,'2602');
$Product63AGL001=rgar( $entry,'2603');
$Product64AFP11=rgar( $entry,'2625');
$Product65AFB13=rgar( $entry,'2656');
$Product66AGS755SSU=rgar( $entry,'2677');
$Product67AGS753SSU=rgar( $entry,'2604');
$Product68AGNPF10=rgar( $entry,'2675');
$Product69AGNPF02=rgar( $entry,'2605');
$Product70AFH50SU=rgar( $entry,'2666');
$Product71AFH75SU=rgar( $entry,'2645');
$Product72AII5000=rgar( $entry,'2947');
$Product73AII2500=rgar( $entry,'2946');
$Product74KD160=rgar( $entry,'2608');
$Product75APD101SSU=rgar( $entry,'2611');
$Product76APD102SSU=rgar( $entry,'2612');
$Product77APD100SSU=rgar( $entry,'2614');
$Product78APD50SSU=rgar( $entry,'2613');
$Product79APD75SSU=rgar( $entry,'2653');
$Product80AP312SU=rgar( $entry,'2609');
$Product81AP325DSU=rgar( $entry,'2679');
$Product82ND90=rgar( $entry,'2622');
$Product83APD100S=rgar( $entry,'2680');
$Product84APD101S=rgar( $entry,'2681');
$Product85APD102S=rgar( $entry,'2682');
$Product86APD50S=rgar( $entry,'2683');
$Product87APD75S=rgar( $entry,'2684');
$Product88AGS75=rgar( $entry,'2676');
$Product89ABN10SU=rgar( $entry,'2695');
$Product90ABN10=rgar( $entry,'2626');
$Product91ASN096P=rgar( $entry,'2615');
$Product92AP10125=rgar( $entry,'2617');
$Product93AP1015=rgar( $entry,'2618');
$Product94PPC60=rgar( $entry,'2691');
$Product95AWP16100SU=rgar( $entry,'2686');
$Product96ASP12=rgar( $entry,'2620');
$Product97ASC13=rgar( $entry,'2621');
$Product98AFSB10=rgar( $entry,'2673');
$Product99AFSB10SU=rgar( $entry,'2674');
$Product100AFHSB100=rgar( $entry,'2667');
$Product101AFHSB100SU=rgar( $entry,'2668');
$Product102AW1060SU=rgar( $entry,'2597');
$Product103SOFTTWR=rgar( $entry,'2692');
$Product104ASP100SU=rgar( $entry,'2624');
$Product105Stingoes25=rgar( $entry,'2963');
$Product106AT25SU=rgar( $entry,'2610');
$Product107AF9=rgar( $entry,'2627');
$Product108USP19=rgar( $entry,'2693');
$Product109AW1510SU=rgar( $entry,'2644');
$Product110APWC7535SU=rgar( $entry,'2623');
$Product111AWD13SSU=rgar( $entry,'2628');
$Product112AWD14SSU=rgar( $entry,'2629');
$Product113AWD15SSU=rgar( $entry,'2630');
$Product114AFT25SU=rgar( $entry,'2631');
$Product115AFPW010SU=rgar( $entry,'2970');
$Product116AFPW015SU=rgar( $entry,'2977');
$Quantity1AM01=rgar( $entry,'2835');
$Quantity2AFP601=rgar( $entry,'2793');
$Quantity3AFP6015=rgar( $entry,'2799');
$Quantity4AFID6SSU=rgar( $entry,'2781');
$Quantity5AFID8SSU=rgar( $entry,'2787');
$Quantity6AP101=rgar( $entry,'2841');
$Quantity7AW8110=rgar( $entry,'2889');
$Quantity8AW7100SU=rgar( $entry,'119');
$Quantity9AAB100=rgar( $entry,'175');
$Quantity10EGA60=rgar( $entry,'2907');
$Quantity11AA01=rgar( $entry,'1278');
$Quantity12AAS50=rgar( $entry,'198');
$Quantity13AW8000SU=rgar( $entry,'216');
$Quantity14BHB2538=rgar( $entry,'2901');
$Quantity15AB3=rgar( $entry,'1987');
$Quantity16ABD10=rgar( $entry,'234');
$Quantity17ABS1010SU=rgar( $entry,'270');
$Quantity18ABC10=rgar( $entry,'2960');
$Quantity19ABC10SU=rgar( $entry,'2548');
$Quantity20ST30SU=rgar( $entry,'306');
$Quantity21FCP03=rgar( $entry,'2913');
$Quantity22FCP06=rgar( $entry,'2919');
$Quantity23ABCH100SU=rgar( $entry,'2530');
$Quantity24ABCH100=rgar( $entry,'2943');
$Quantity25ABCH25=rgar( $entry,'2953');
$Quantity26ABCH25SU=rgar( $entry,'2534');
$Quantity27ABCH50SU=rgar( $entry,'2542');
$Quantity28ABCH50=rgar( $entry,'2713');
$Quantity29ABCH75=rgar( $entry,'2719');
$Quantity30ABCH75SU=rgar( $entry,'2538');
$Quantity31ACD1010SSU=rgar( $entry,'324');
$Quantity32ACD1020SSU=rgar( $entry,'342');
$Quantity33ACD2020SSU=rgar( $entry,'360');
$Quantity34AF100SU=rgar( $entry,'2757');
$Quantity35AF25SU=rgar( $entry,'378');
$Quantity36AF50SU=rgar( $entry,'396');
$Quantity37AF75SU=rgar( $entry,'414');
$Quantity38ACA150=rgar( $entry,'468');
$Quantity39CWD001=rgar( $entry,'288');
$Quantity40ACM100SU=rgar( $entry,'2731');
$Quantity41ACM150SU=rgar( $entry,'2737');
$Quantity42ACM25SU=rgar( $entry,'2743');
$Quantity43ACM50SU=rgar( $entry,'522');
$Quantity44ACM75SU=rgar( $entry,'540');
$Quantity45AD1007B=rgar( $entry,'2751');
$Quantity46AD1000=rgar( $entry,'2514');
$Quantity47AD1001=rgar( $entry,'2518');
$Quantity48PTD06=rgar( $entry,'1008');
$Quantity49AWDPB01=rgar( $entry,'558');
$Quantity50ACE50SU=rgar( $entry,'2554');
$Quantity51ATB130=rgar( $entry,'576');
$Quantity52ATB130SU=rgar( $entry,'2883');
$Quantity53AEP1SSU=rgar( $entry,'1314');
$Quantity54EB001=rgar( $entry,'612');
$Quantity55AFP701=rgar( $entry,'630');
$Quantity56AFP50125=rgar( $entry,'2526');
$Quantity57AFP350=rgar( $entry,'2017');
$Quantity58AFP506=rgar( $entry,'2522');
$Quantity59AFP501=rgar( $entry,'1026');
$Quantity60AFP5015=rgar( $entry,'2032');
$Quantity61AFS001=rgar( $entry,'1404');
$Quantity62AGB001=rgar( $entry,'684');
$Quantity63AGL001=rgar( $entry,'1350');
$Quantity64AFP11=rgar( $entry,'2246');
$Quantity65AFB13=rgar( $entry,'2510');
$Quantity66AGS755SSU=rgar( $entry,'2829');
$Quantity67AGS753SSU=rgar( $entry,'702');
$Quantity68AGNPF10=rgar( $entry,'2817');
$Quantity69AGNPF02=rgar( $entry,'720');
$Quantity70AFH50SU=rgar( $entry,'2763');
$Quantity71AFH75SU=rgar( $entry,'2505');
$Quantity72AII5000=rgar( $entry,'792');
$Quantity73AII2500=rgar( $entry,'810');
$Quantity74KD160=rgar( $entry,'864');
$Quantity75APD101SSU=rgar( $entry,'1473');
$Quantity76APD102SSU=rgar( $entry,'936');
$Quantity77APD100SSU=rgar( $entry,'972');
$Quantity78APD50SSU=rgar( $entry,'954');
$Quantity79APD75SSU=rgar( $entry,'2560');
$Quantity80AP312SU=rgar( $entry,'1368');
$Quantity81AP325DSU=rgar( $entry,'2847');
$Quantity82ND90=rgar( $entry,'1501');
$Quantity83APD100S=rgar( $entry,'2853');
$Quantity84APD101S=rgar( $entry,'2859');
$Quantity85APD102S=rgar( $entry,'2865');
$Quantity86APD50S=rgar( $entry,'2871');
$Quantity87APD75S=rgar( $entry,'2877');
$Quantity88AGS75=rgar( $entry,'2823');
$Quantity89ABN10SU=rgar( $entry,'2725');
$Quantity90ABN10=rgar( $entry,'1188');
$Quantity91ASN096P=rgar( $entry,'990');
$Quantity92AP10125=rgar( $entry,'1386');
$Quantity93AP1015=rgar( $entry,'1487');
$Quantity94PPC60=rgar( $entry,'2925');
$Quantity95AWP16100SU=rgar( $entry,'2895');
$Quantity96ASP12=rgar( $entry,'1080');
$Quantity97ASC13=rgar( $entry,'1098');
$Quantity98AFSB10=rgar( $entry,'2805');
$Quantity99AFSB10SU=rgar( $entry,'2811');
$Quantity100AFHSB100=rgar( $entry,'2769');
$Quantity101AFHSB100SU=rgar( $entry,'2775');
$Quantity102AW1060SU=rgar( $entry,'1332');
$Quantity103SOFTTWR=rgar( $entry,'2931');
$Quantity104ASP100SU=rgar( $entry,'1152');
$Quantity105Stingoes25=rgar( $entry,'2967');
$Quantity106AT25SU=rgar( $entry,'900');
$Quantity107AF9=rgar( $entry,'1515');
$Quantity108USP19=rgar( $entry,'2937');
$Quantity109AW1510SU=rgar( $entry,'2482');
$Quantity110APWC7535SU=rgar( $entry,'1134');
$Quantity111AWD13SSU=rgar( $entry,'1206');
$Quantity112AWD14SSU=rgar( $entry,'1224');
$Quantity113AWD15SSU=rgar( $entry,'1242');
$Quantity114AFT25SU=rgar( $entry,'1260');
$Quantity115AFPW010SU=rgar( $entry,'2974');
$Quantity116AFPW015SU=rgar( $entry,'2981');
$word = "created";

     
// Test if string contains the word 
if(strpos($doyouorder, $word) !== true){
    
WC()->cart->set_session();  
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product1AM01,$Quantity1AM01,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product2AFP601,$Quantity2AFP601,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product3AFP6015,$Quantity3AFP6015,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product4AFID6SSU,$Quantity4AFID6SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product5AFID8SSU,$Quantity5AFID8SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product6AP101,$Quantity6AP101,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product7AW8110,$Quantity7AW8110,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product8AW7100SU,$Quantity8AW7100SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product9AAB100,$Quantity9AAB100,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product10EGA60,$Quantity10EGA60,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product11AA01,$Quantity11AA01,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product12AAS50,$Quantity12AAS50,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product13AW8000SU,$Quantity13AW8000SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product14BHB2538,$Quantity14BHB2538,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product15AB3,$Quantity15AB3,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product16ABD10,$Quantity16ABD10,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product17ABS1010SU,$Quantity17ABS1010SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product18ABC10,$Quantity18ABC10,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product19ABC10SU,$Quantity19ABC10SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product20ST30SU,$Quantity20ST30SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product21FCP03,$Quantity21FCP03,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product22FCP06,$Quantity22FCP06,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product23ABCH100SU,$Quantity23ABCH100SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product24ABCH100,$Quantity24ABCH100,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product25ABCH25,$Quantity25ABCH25,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product26ABCH25SU,$Quantity26ABCH25SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product27ABCH50SU,$Quantity27ABCH50SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product28ABCH50,$Quantity28ABCH50,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product29ABCH75,$Quantity29ABCH75,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product30ABCH75SU,$Quantity30ABCH75SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product31ACD1010SSU,$Quantity31ACD1010SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product32ACD1020SSU,$Quantity32ACD1020SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product33ACD2020SSU,$Quantity33ACD2020SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product34AF100SU,$Quantity34AF100SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product35AF25SU,$Quantity35AF25SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product36AF50SU,$Quantity36AF50SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product37AF75SU,$Quantity37AF75SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product38ACA150,$Quantity38ACA150,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product39CWD001,$Quantity39CWD001,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product40ACM100SU,$Quantity40ACM100SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product41ACM150SU,$Quantity41ACM150SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product42ACM25SU,$Quantity42ACM25SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product43ACM50SU,$Quantity43ACM50SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product44ACM75SU,$Quantity44ACM75SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product45AD1007B,$Quantity45AD1007B,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product46AD1000,$Quantity46AD1000,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product47AD1001,$Quantity47AD1001,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product48PTD06,$Quantity48PTD06,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product49AWDPB01,$Quantity49AWDPB01,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product50ACE50SU,$Quantity50ACE50SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product51ATB130,$Quantity51ATB130,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product52ATB130SU,$Quantity52ATB130SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product53AEP1SSU,$Quantity53AEP1SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product54EB001,$Quantity54EB001,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product55AFP701,$Quantity55AFP701,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product56AFP50125,$Quantity56AFP50125,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product57AFP350,$Quantity57AFP350,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product58AFP506,$Quantity58AFP506,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product59AFP501,$Quantity59AFP501,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product60AFP5015,$Quantity60AFP5015,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product61AFS001,$Quantity61AFS001,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product62AGB001,$Quantity62AGB001,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product63AGL001,$Quantity63AGL001,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product64AFP11,$Quantity64AFP11,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product65AFB13,$Quantity65AFB13,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product66AGS755SSU,$Quantity66AGS755SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product67AGS753SSU,$Quantity67AGS753SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product68AGNPF10,$Quantity68AGNPF10,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product69AGNPF02,$Quantity69AGNPF02,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product70AFH50SU,$Quantity70AFH50SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product71AFH75SU,$Quantity71AFH75SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product72AII5000,$Quantity72AII5000,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product73AII2500,$Quantity73AII2500,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product74KD160,$Quantity74KD160,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product75APD101SSU,$Quantity75APD101SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product76APD102SSU,$Quantity76APD102SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product77APD100SSU,$Quantity77APD100SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product78APD50SSU,$Quantity78APD50SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product79APD75SSU,$Quantity79APD75SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product80AP312SU,$Quantity80AP312SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product81AP325DSU,$Quantity81AP325DSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product82ND90,$Quantity82ND90,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product83APD100S,$Quantity83APD100S,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product84APD101S,$Quantity84APD101S,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product85APD102S,$Quantity85APD102S,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product86APD50S,$Quantity86APD50S,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product87APD75S,$Quantity87APD75S,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product88AGS75,$Quantity88AGS75,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product89ABN10SU,$Quantity89ABN10SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product90ABN10,$Quantity90ABN10,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product91ASN096P,$Quantity91ASN096P,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product92AP10125,$Quantity92AP10125,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product93AP1015,$Quantity93AP1015,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product94PPC60,$Quantity94PPC60,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product95AWP16100SU,$Quantity95AWP16100SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product96ASP12,$Quantity96ASP12,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product97ASC13,$Quantity97ASC13,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product98AFSB10,$Quantity98AFSB10,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product99AFSB10SU,$Quantity99AFSB10SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product100AFHSB100,$Quantity100AFHSB100,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product101AFHSB100SU,$Quantity101AFHSB100SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product102AW1060SU,$Quantity102AW1060SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product103SOFTTWR,$Quantity103SOFTTWR,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product104ASP100SU,$Quantity104ASP100SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product105Stingoes25,$Quantity105Stingoes25,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product106AT25SU,$Quantity106AT25SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product107AF9,$Quantity107AF9,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product108USP19,$Quantity108USP19,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product109AW1510SU,$Quantity109AW1510SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product110APWC7535SU,$Quantity110APWC7535SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product111AWD13SSU,$Quantity111AWD13SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product112AWD14SSU,$Quantity112AWD14SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product113AWD15SSU,$Quantity113AWD15SSU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product114AFT25SU,$Quantity114AFT25SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product115AFPW010SU,$Quantity115AFPW010SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($Product116AFPW015SU,$Quantity116AFPW015SU,0,array(),array('add_size' => array('Belonging to Kit'=> $kitnote)));


}}
```